# How to do a division from calculated values from one table in a single query

Tags: sql, division

I have the following SQL query and I want to calculate a derivated field, A/B:

```
select center, month, sum(countA) as A, sum(countB) as B, A/B 
from counter
group by center, month
```

However, this sentence throws an error, and I would wish to not repeat the sum again. Is there any way to do that on a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
select center, month, A, B, A/B from
(
    select center, month, sum(countA) as A, sum(countB) as B
    from counter
    group by center, month
)
```

But you may still get an error if B is zero. To account for this, try this:

```
select center, month, A, B, case when B = 0 then 0 else A/B end from
(
    select center, month, sum(countA) as A, sum(countB) as B 
    from counter
    group by center, month
)
```

Comment: But by doing that, aren't you running through the counter + result of the subquery? What about if counter has 70 million files for example and the resulting subquery is about 30 million?

Do you mean that to do that simple division for each file, I have to go through those 100 million and just running 70 is not enough?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, aliases are not known in the same select clause.  You can do the calculation as:

```
select center, month, sum(countA) as A, sum(countB) as B, sum(countA) / sum(countB)
from counter
group by center, month;
```

You can also do this in a subquery:

```
select center, month, A, B, A/B
from (select center, month, usm(countA) as A, sum(countB) as B
      from counter
      group by center, month
     ) t
```